# Joda DateTime object adding +1 hour

Tags: android, jodatime

i have the following code:

```
        Log.e(TAG, "startTime = " + startTime);

        DateTime dateTimeStart = new DateTime(startTime);

        Log.e(TAG, "dateTimeStart = " + dateTimeStart  );
```

.

which when logged out produces the following:

```
 startTime = 2014-10-30T12:00:00+00:00

dateTimeStart = 2014-10-30T13:00:00.000+01:00
```

.

Why is an extra hour getting added on to the original time?

edit
How can i remove the +1:00, i haven't specified that.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` is an object consisting of a date, a time, and a timezone. In your case, you took `startTime` and converted it into an equivalent `DateTime` using the default system timezone.

`+01:00` means "this timestamp is in some UTC+1 timezone", so `12:00:00.000+00:00` means the same as `13:00:00.000+01:00`

So your timestamp was created at 12:00 British time = 13:00 Central European time.

If you want the time in UTC, do

```
DateTime dateTimeStart = new DateTime(startTime, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split method.

```
 String splitDateTime[]=dateTimeStart.split("\\+");

 dateTimeStart=splitDateTime[0];
```

Comment: `+` is not a valid regex.

Answer (score 0):

Default `DateTime::toString()` method returns date in format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ` .
`+01:00` and `+00:00` are the timezone offsets (`ZZ` in date format).

So if you want to print date without timezone offset, you should use another format. E.g. with method `DateTime::toString(String)`:

```
String dtFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
Log.e(TAG, "startTime = " + startTime.toString(dtFormat));   
...  

Log.e(TAG, "dateTimeStart = " + dateTimeStart.toString(dtFormat ));
```